# SVG изображение. Как сделать его path?

Tags: html, css, svg

Не могу нормально разобраться с `path` (SVG). Может кто помочь сделать такую вот вроде бы "несложную" штуку? Был бы чрезмерно благодарен, или дайте наводку.
Можно сделать и без плавных кривых, просто срез.
 Опять же, я был бы очень признателен, это только просьба.
Ширина примерно на `50px`. `ViewBox=" 0 0 50 50"`

И как лучше такой штуке задать тень?

[image: штука]

Comment: Это вы всмысле собрались вручную её написать ? Похвально конечно, но лучше не майтесь дурью, поставьте inkscape (или illustrator, если не против пиратсва) и нарисуйте фигуру там.

Comment: @Hikikomori, кривые Безье можно и вручную=) (может даже несколько быстрее)

Comment: @Arthur Это если знаешь, что и как делать, а это явно не случай автора

Comment: Даже ставить ничего не нужно, много онлайн тулз: https://www.janvas.com/v6.1/janvas_app_6.1_public/index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ответ будет подробный для начинающих изучать SVG.

*Используя данную технику, легко получить любую простую или сложную фигуру SVG, которая будет адаптивна и будет одинаково выглядеть во всех браузерах.*

### Техника получения path по заданной картинке

- Пишем код svg для добавления вашей картинки в векторный редактор.
  Картинка имеет размеры `380x50 px`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="380" height="50" viewBox="0 0 380 50" >  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7DqM.png" width="380" height="50" />
</svg>
```

- В векторном редакторе с помощью инструмента -**"Добавлять кривые
  Безье"** (на рисунке цифра 1) - наносим по границам рисунка узловые
  точки

  При необходимости корректируем положение узловых точек (инструмент 2)
  перетаскиванием и форму кривых изменяем рычагами узловых точек.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохраняем файл в векторном редакторе в формате SVG. Из этого файла
  нам нужна только формула патча. Копируем её в рабочий файл.
- Дорабатываем стили - убираем обводку и добавляем цвет

  `style="fill:#F44D3D;stroke:none"`

*Фигура SVG готова:*

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="380" height="50" viewBox="0 0 380 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"> 

<path  d="M3.5 9.8 377.8 8.9l-66.4 33.6-6.1 1.7-8.3 1.7-8.7 1.3c0 0-147.8 0.7-221.9 0-2.6 0-4.2-0.5-7.6-1.9-3.3-1.3-4.4-1.8-6.4-2.9C35.3 33 3.5 9.8 3.5 9.8Z" style="fill:#F44D3D;stroke:none"/>

</svg>
```

### Делаем фигуру SVG полностью адаптивной

Для этого заменяем для ширины и высоты пользовательского окна просмотра пиксели на проценты. Для того, чтобы фигура знимала весь экран браузера присваивается `width="100%"` `height="100%"`
 Для размеров, как у автора вопроса `width="25%"` `height="25%"`

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="25%" height="25%" viewBox="0 0 380 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"> 

<path  d="M3.5 9.8 377.8 8.9l-66.4 33.6-6.1 1.7-8.3 1.7-8.7 1.3c0 0-147.8 0.7-221.9 0-2.6 0-4.2-0.5-7.6-1.9-3.3-1.3-4.4-1.8-6.4-2.9C35.3 33 3.5 9.8 3.5 9.8Z" style="fill:#F44D3D;stroke:none"/>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 6):

### Добавление тени CSS

```css
.container {
filter:drop-shadow(2px 4px 3px black);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="25%" height="25%" viewBox="0 0 380 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"> 

<path id="shadow"   d="M3.5 9.8 377.8 8.9l-66.4 33.6-6.1 1.7-8.3 1.7-8.7 1.3c0 0-147.8 0.7-221.9 0-2.6 0-4.2-0.5-7.6-1.9-3.3-1.3-4.4-1.8-6.4-2.9C35.3 33 3.5 9.8 3.5 9.8Z" style="fill:#F44D3D;stroke:none"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

### Добавление тени SVG

Код немного сложнее варианта CSS, но выглядит тень SVG более реалистично и имеет несколько возможностей для регулировки внешнего вида.

- Делаем копию патча основной фигуры и сдвигаем копию влево и вниз на
  несколько пикселей:

`<path id="pathCopy" transform="translate(2 2)"  d="M3.5 9.8 377.8 8.9l-66.4 33.6-6.1 1.7-8.3 1.7-8.7 1.3c0 0-147.8 0.7-221.9 0-2.6 0-4.2-0.5-7.6-1.9-3.3-1.3-4.4-1.8-6.4-2.9C35.3 33 3.5 9.8 3.5 9.8Z" style="fill:white;stroke:none"/>`

- Применяем к копии патча, которая расположена ниже основного патча
  фигуры фильтр размытия Гаусса:

```css
#pathCopy {
filter:url(#shadow);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="mySvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 380 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"> 
<defs>
  <filter id="shadow" x="-10%" y="10%" height="140%" width="140%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"/> 
 </defs>
 <path id="pathCopy" transform="translate(2 2)"  d="M3.5 9.8 377.8 8.9l-66.4 33.6-6.1 1.7-8.3 1.7-8.7 1.3c0 0-147.8 0.7-221.9 0-2.6 0-4.2-0.5-7.6-1.9-3.3-1.3-4.4-1.8-6.4-2.9C35.3 33 3.5 9.8 3.5 9.8Z" style="fill:white;stroke:none"/>
<path id="path1"   d="M3.5 9.8 377.8 8.9l-66.4 33.6-6.1 1.7-8.3 1.7-8.7 1.3c0 0-147.8 0.7-221.9 0-2.6 0-4.2-0.5-7.6-1.9-3.3-1.3-4.4-1.8-6.4-2.9C35.3 33 3.5 9.8 3.5 9.8Z" style="fill:#F44D3D;stroke:none"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

### SVG filter feDropShadow

```css
#path1 {
filter:url(#shadow); 
fill:#F44D3D;
stroke:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 380 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" > 

 <defs>
        <filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-10%" width="160%" height="160%">
            <feDropShadow dx="2" dy="2" stdDeviation="3"/>
        </filter>
 </defs>

<path id="path1"   d="M3.5 9.8 377.8 8.9l-66.4 33.6-6.1 1.7-8.3 1.7-8.7 1.3c0 0-147.8 0.7-221.9 0-2.6 0-4.2-0.5-7.6-1.9-3.3-1.3-4.4-1.8-6.4-2.9C35.3 33 3.5 9.8 3.5 9.8Z" />
</svg>
</div>
```

**Update**

Сниппет искажает (подрезает снизу) тень. В браузерах этого не наблюдается

Для регулировки внешнего вида тени по своему вкусу используйте атрибуты фильтра - `dx="2"` `dy="2"` `stdDeviation="3"`